# Laravel 5, Derived table in join clause?

Tags: left-join, laravel-5, query-builder, derived-table

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM blog
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT blog_id, AVG(value) as blog_rating FROM blog_ratings
    GROUP BY (blog_id)
) T ON T.blog_id = blog.id;
```

I do not know how to write this with Eloquent.

For Example:

```
Blog::select("*")->leftJoin( /* Here goes derived table */ )->get()
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd personally just use the fluent query builder, try this out and see how it works out:

```
DB::table('blog')
  ->select('*')
  ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT blog_id, AVG(value) as blog_rating FROM blog_ratings
    GROUP BY (blog_id)
    ) as T'), function ($join) {
        $join->on ( 'T.blog_id', '=', 'blog.id' );
    })
  ->get();
```

You can always swap `->get()` for `->toSql()` to dump out the query and adjust if you see any mistakes.

Comment: Since I cannot use DB::table as it will not give me model (I have relations that are needed for representing data) I came up with this


`Blog::leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT blog_id, AVG(value) as blog_rating FROM blog_ratings GROUP BY (blog_id)) as T'), function ($join) {$join->on ( 'T.blog_id', '=', 'blog.id' );})->get();`

Comment: learning that you can pass the raw derived table sql as the first argument to a *join function, rather than the table name, was clutch